# How to pass props between routes in Nextjs App router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, next.js13, app-router

I am using **App router** and I want to pass parameters as `object` without using `useParams` & `useSearchParams`

If I were to have a object say `person`

```
const person: Person = {
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 25,
  address: "123 Main St",
};
```

I want to send `person` object from one route to another lets say from `/home` to `/person`

Persently as per my limited knowledge you can move from one route to another using

1. `router.push()`
2. `Link's href`

But I cannot see any argument were I can pass the complete object

Comment: I think you should use sessionStorage or some global state manager like context or redux or mobx. 
You can read from this link to know that there is current no way to pass prop between router https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17008
Sorry that if you're already know what I comment

Answer (score 0):

For me this works perfectly to pass objects to other components, plus it is a server side code, maybe it will help u:

in `/home` put it like this

```
export default function Home() { 

  var person: object = {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 25,
    address: "123 Main St",
  };

  return ( 
    ...

    <Login myObj={person}/>

    ...
  )};
```

then in `/person` use it like this

```
export default function person(props : any) {

return (
   ... 
  
   <p {props.myObj.name}</p>
   <p {props.myObj.age}</p>
   <p {props.myObj.address}</p>

   ...
)};
```